# How to Display Only One Column of a Result in Table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am new to PHP and I am having trouble displaying results from a MySQL query.

So I have a table called Teams, and it contains two fields per entry:
Name, and Continent.

I send a query to the MySQL database to grab all the records where the Continent field equals "Asia." Then I am trying to print only the names of these teams in an HTML table.

Right now I can get the desired names, however my table has an extra empty column on the right and I don't understand how to get rid of it.

Here is my code:

```
$query = 
    "SELECT name from Teams WHERE continent='Asia'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(!$result){
        echo 'Retreive Query Fail' . mysql_error();
    }
?>

<div style="text-align: center; color: #000000">
    Teams in Asia
</div>

<table>

    <caption>
        <dfn title="my table"></dfn>
    </caption>

    <tr>
        <th>Team Names</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $row["name"] . '<td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

And here is a picture of the result, the thing I want to get rid of is those boxes on the right of the table. (Please ignore the horrendous color scheme / layout. I have never done web design before.)

[image: Image of Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your `<td>` tag properly instead of adding another one:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row["name"] . '</td>';
                            // ^ This guy.
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Gah! Always the little things! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<td>' . $row["name"] . '<td>';
```

should be

```
echo '<td>' . $row["name"] . '</td>';
```